# Unstringize inside a Macro

Tags: c++

Inside a Macro, I can use the stringizing operator `#`:

```
#define STRINGIZE(name) #name

cout << STRINGIZE(SomeClass) << endl; // Prints "SomeClass"
```

Is it possible to do the opposite, *unstringize* inside a Macro? How?

For example:

```
#define RUN_FUNCTION(name) UNSTRINGIZE(name)();

void myFunction {
  cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}

RUN_FUNCTION("myFunction") // Prints "Hello!"
```

If not, is there a reason why?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do this, since `"myFunction"` needs to be a compile-time string constant (the only kind of string accessible to the preprocessor)?

Comment: I'm tolerably certain it cannot be done.  One reason might be no-one had a need for it.  There'd be some interesting issues to resolve.

Comment: Actually I don't need this, I'm just curious. I asked myself if there was an unstringify operator after reading a question where the OP wanted to call a function from user input

Comment: No, it's not possible. It would just make the preprocessor more complicated (introduce two types in the macro language, "anything goes" and "only strings please") with no apparent need. Plus, unstringizing is not trivial (what's `UNSTRINGIZE("\x9f")`?)

Comment: @alestanis, Preprocessing takes place before compilation, which is before runtime. You'd need reflection to do that without defining your own rules, which requires some form of metadata, and C++ doesn't have it.

Comment: @alestanis even if it would be possible, then for sure you cannot apply preprocessor on user input. And it has not sense - why one would write `RUN_FUNCTION("myFunction")` instead of `myFunction`. Try to find real world example where it would be useful...

Comment: @PiotrNycz As I said before, I thought about this question from a person this morning asking how he could call a function from user input. You have N functions called `function1` ... `functionN`, and you ask the user which one he wants. The user inputs `"function42"`. How do you launch it? I don't care that you can do this with a `hash_map` or a `switch` statement. My question "has sense" because I don't know what the string will be so I can't just call `function42()`. I just wanted to understand why it wouldn't be possible to have an unstringify operator.

Comment: FWIW, I actually ran into this issue a few days ago. Some integer data is written as a string, and I wanted to manipulate that integer at compile-time so I wanted to strip the quotes (the code base is too large to simply change the integer). I already knew it was impossible though, so wasted no time. You guys are getting too hung up on the motivational reason; sometimes people just ask questions out of curiosity.

Comment: I have an example also. I want to name a function based on the filename, so I do (obviously with pasting indirection) `function_##__FILE__` and I get an error: `function_"filename"` 'pasting formed invalid token....'  Both gcc and clang expand `__FILE__` to a runtime c string, so my macro breaks.  I'll have to find a "better" way, but the sentiment that "I can't think why you'd want to, therefore it's a bad idea" has historically always failed to be useful. (Also, I have to use a `#line` directive to strip the `.c` extension.  comp-time string manipulation is also a good idea, and trivial.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Promoted from comment]
Preprocessing takes place before compilation, which is before runtime. You'd need reflection to do that without defining your own rules, which requires some form of metadata, and C++ doesn't have it.

I can't find where, but I recently saw somewhere (perhaps [here](http://isocpp.org/), but according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Features_removed_or_deprecated), it's been postponed) that reflection could be coming to C++ sometime in the future, so there might be a prospect there.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.  The C++ preprocessor cannot break up tokens into smaller tokens in any way.

What exactly is it that you're trying to do?  There's almost certainly a better way of doing it.